# Expression: vector erase iterator outside range when using vector.erase()

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and was trying to write a program that takes the lowest and the highest numbers in a vector, takes them away from the vector and proceeds to calculate an average with the rest of the numbers.

Now while I understand that I could do it after the numbers have been entered, I wanted to challenge myself and carry out these checks as the numbers were entered one by one. I was looking around but I couldn't find another person with the exact issue I am having (since I am using vector.end() - 1).

Below is my code and the error that it is giving me. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <limits.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    typedef vector<int>::iterator iter;
    
    int main() {
    
        cout << "Please enter the series of scores: \n";
    
        // Read numbers from the standard input
        // and store them in a vector
        vector<int> scoreVector;
        int x = 0;
        int count = 0;
        // Assign the lowest possible value to the maximum possible integer so that any value entered initially will be lower that INT_MAX
        int lowestValue = INT_MAX;
        int highestValue = 0;
    
        iter lowestValueIndex;
        iter highestValueIndex;
    
        // Every time a number is entered, the program checks to see if it meets the criteria for the lowest or highest number entered so far
        while (cin >> x) {
    
            scoreVector.push_back(x);
    
            if (x > highestValue) {
                highestValueIndex = scoreVector.end() - 1;
                highestValue = x;
            }
            if (x < lowestValue) {
                lowestValueIndex = scoreVector.end() - 1;
                lowestValue = x;
            }
        }
    
        // Calculate the vector size
        auto n = scoreVector.size();
        
    
        if (n > 2) {
            
            cout << "\nThe lowest value is:" << lowestValue << "\nThe highest value is: " << highestValue << ". These values have been taken out." << '\n';
    
            // Remove the two values from the vector
            scoreVector.erase(lowestValueIndex);
            scoreVector.erase(highestValueIndex);
    
            // Calculate the average
            auto average = accumulate(scoreVector.begin(), scoreVector.end(), 0.0) / n;
    
            cout << "\naverage = " << average << '\n';
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, you are taking iterators to `scoreVector`. However, every time you do a `push_back` on a `vector`, all iterators to it are invalidated. This means that when you exit your `while` loop, at least one if not both iterators are dangling. Passing those iterators to `.erase` then invokes undefined behavior.

Instead, you should separate out the reading of the variables, and computation of the iterators that you want to erase:

```
while (cin >> x) { 
    scoreVector.push_back(x);
}

iter lowestValueIndex = std::min_element(scoreVector.begin(), scoreVector.end());
scoreVector.erase(lowestValueIndex);

iter highestValueIndex = std::max_element(scoreVector.begin(), scoreVector.end());
scoreVector.erase(highestValueIndex);
```

Comment: Be careful because `erase` will invalidate iterators for elements after the erased element.

Comment: Thank you all for the amazing help, I was not aware that iterators can be invalidated like this. I was originally thinking of vectors like arrays but boy was I wrong!

I have re-written the code and with a few tweaks, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules), `scoreVector.push_back(x);` may invalidate iterators taken before that by causing reallocation.

You should save indice instead of iterators as indice.

Also be careful because `erase` will shift following elements and it may affect indice of the element to be erased.

Try this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <limits.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    typedef vector<int>::iterator iter;
    
    int main() {
    
        cout << "Please enter the series of scores: \n";
    
        // Read numbers from the standard input
        // and store them in a vector
        vector<int> scoreVector;
        int x = 0;
        int count = 0;
        // Assign the lowest possible value to the maximum possible integer so that any value entered initially will be lower that INT_MAX
        int lowestValue = INT_MAX;
        int highestValue = 0;
    
        size_t lowestValueIndex = 0;
        size_t highestValueIndex = 0;
    
        // Every time a number is entered, the program checks to see if it meets the criteria for the lowest or highest number entered so far
        while (cin >> x) {
    
            scoreVector.push_back(x);
    
            if (x > highestValue) {
                highestValueIndex = scoreVector.size() - 1;
                highestValue = x;
            }
            if (x < lowestValue) {
                lowestValueIndex = scoreVector.size() - 1;
                lowestValue = x;
            }
        }
    
        // Calculate the vector size
        auto n = scoreVector.size();
        
    
        if (n > 2) {
            
            cout << "\nThe lowest value is:" << lowestValue << "\nThe highest value is: " << highestValue << ". These values have been taken out." << '\n';
    
            // Remove the two values from the vector
            scoreVector.erase(std::next(scoreVector.begin(), lowestValueIndex));
            if (lowestValueIndex < highestValueIndex) highestValueIndex--;
            scoreVector.erase(std::next(scoreVector.begin(), highestValueIndex));
    
            // Calculate the average
            auto average = accumulate(scoreVector.begin(), scoreVector.end(), 0.0) / n;
    
            cout << "\naverage = " << average << '\n';
        }
        return 0;
    }
```